# Least square method in general

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

If I have this points given:
$f(\frac{1}{2})=-1$ , $f(1)=2$, $f(3)=4$, $f(9)=5$, $f(81)=8$. How can I fit the curve with the following form: $f(x)=a_0+a_1\log_3 x$?

Also in general :$f(x)=a_0 g(x)+a_1 h(x)$

Comment: Minimize the square difference between the 4-vectors $y = (-1, 2,, 4, 5, 8)$ and $a_0 (g(1/2), g(1), g(3), g(9), g(81)) + a_1 (h(1/2), h(1), h(3), h(9), h(81)).$ This leads to the equation $\min_x (y - Ax)$ for a matrix $A$ and unknown $x = (a_0, a_1)$. The solution is $x = (A^t A)^{-1} A^t y$.

Comment: That actually make sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Partial **Hint:** In the first case you minimize $S(a_0,a_1)$

$=(-1-(a_0+a_1\cdot \log_3(1/2))^2+(2-(a_0+a_1\cdot \log_3(1))^2$

$+(4-(a_0+a_1\cdot \log_3(3))^2+(5-(a_0+a_1\cdot \log_3(9))^2$

$+(8-(a_0+a_1\cdot \log_3(81))^2$

So you calculate the partial derivatives w.r.t $a_0$ and $a_1$ and set them equal to $0$, respectively. Then solve this small equation system for $a_0$ and $a_1$. Useful:

- The derivative of a sum is equal to the sum of the derivatives.
- The derivative of the first sumand w.r.t $a_1$ is $2\cdot   
     (-1-(a_0+a_1\cdot \log_3(1/2))\cdot \left(-\log_3(1/2)\right)$

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You´re welcome. It would be more comfortable if the first x-value would be 1/3, or more general $1/3^x$. Then the logarithm would be easy to calculate.

Comment: I just double checked on my paper and its 1/3 so even better.

Comment: @Physics_student So you are lucky: $\log_3(1/3)=-\log_3(3)=-1$. All other x-values can be written in the form $3^x$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have $n$ data points $(x_i,y_i)$ and you want to fit the model
$$y=a_0 \,g(x)+a_1\, h(x)$$ where $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are known, define two variables $u_i=g(x_i)$, $v_i=h(x_i)$ and you model is simply
$$y=a_0\,u+a_1\,v$$ which is a multilinear regression with no intercept. This is easy to solve using matrix calculations. Otherwise, write the so-called normal equations
$$\sum_{i=1}^n u_i\,y_i=a_0\sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2+a_1\sum_{i=1}^n u_i\,v_i$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\,y_i=a_0\sum_{i=1}^n u_i\,v_i+a_1\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2$$ Two linear equations for two unknowns is quite simple.